# GWT:adding clickHandler on HyperLink

Tags: java, gwt

I am having this HyperLInk in my cellTable ,but its Clickhandler is not working

```
myHyperLInk.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){

  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    Window.alert("test");

 }});
```

It displays a warning :

> The method addClickHandler(ClickHandler) from the type Hyperlink is
>   deprecated

When i click on the link, it simple go to the previous page from history. How can i simply say show a message dialog on pressing a hyperLink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want may be an anchor widget vs a hyperlink.

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Anchor.html

Hyperlinks are usually used for working with the history.

Comment: i want to make it like Href , means when we hover it, mouse arrow change to a thumb .. can i achieve this ?

Comment: but, have u any example of adding this in a celltable

Comment: CellTable, like other Cell widgets, can't have widgets drawn in it. ActionCell and ButtonCell both let you draw buttons with some callback wired to the row - try making a new AbstractCell subclass based on these to get an <a> tag drawn , while still capturing the click events. I'd advise to start with the existing cells to get the behavior right, then move on to drawing it differently.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hyperlink link0 = new Hyperlink("link to foo","foo");
link0.addDomHandler(handler, ClickEvent.getType());


ClickHandler handler = new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
         Window.alert("test");
    }
};
```